# Struggling to install/add JUnit plugin in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I am new to Netbeans and I am trying to install JUnit in the IDE.  I have searched multiple places and can not find a clear answer.  I am running Windows8 with the latest updates and Netbeans 8.0.2.  I have downloaded the jar file for JUnit opened Tools => Plugins then Downloaded tab.  I select the jar file but nothing happens.  I have also tried to run the jar file from commandline and double clicked it and nothing happens.  I am looking to expand my skills sets by practicing using JUnit so any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Not used Netbeans in years, but isn't it installed by default?  It is in IntelliJ and Eclipse.  All you need to do is create a test class with test methods and ask netbeans to run it..... thats how it works in the others.

Answer (score 4):

It is installed by default.
To see that it is installed goto Tools -> Plugins -> Installed and search for JUnit. If it is not there, check Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins before trying your own download.

To use select any java file in the projects directory, right-click Tools -> Create/Update Tests. This will create a stub test file under Test Packages under your Project in the projects tab. 
Select the project and right-click for Test to run all the tests or select any file and right-click for the Test File option.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Netbeans for many years now. However, a quick search shows that during the installation process, there is an option of installing `JUnit` along with Netbeans. The default option(checked) is `Install JUnit`.

If by any chance, the second option(`Do not install JUnit`) got checked, you may want to re-install Netbeans again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I am still using the old 8.0.2 version of Netbeans, and I found out that the install script apparently installs the junit plugin, but not the junit libs. Downloading the following files and adding them as test libs helped:

- junit-4.13.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

At the time of this writing, they could be found here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it,

1. First download the jar file for Junit from this link
   [Junit test jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.1)
2. Then follow along as shown in the images


   Right click on the Library section on your particular project
   [image: Right click on the Library]

   Click on the create button and name Junit(on your preference)->Ok

   [image]

   Then select the Library you created and then select Add Jar/folder
   [image]
   Then select the .jar file you downloaded before and select Add jar folder

   [image]

Now you have setup the Junit library on netbeans